# Viewing a function parameters class methods in python

Tags: python, pycharm

fellow *humans*.

First off, this is my first question here so I apologize if I'm not following the proper etiquette.

I am a 3rd year CS student and fairly new to programming in python with most of my experience coming from C/C++/Java. Something I relied on was the list of methods that is populated when I start typing a functions parameter in dot notation. I am assuming that this is because the parameter's type is defined in the function declaration.

In python, since any object can be passed to any function, how do I get access to this same populated list of the parameter's class methods when writing a function? I always found this extremely useful when a class may be multiple layers of inheritance deep.

Just for reference, I would obviously only want the Python function to be able to accept a specific class or interface. I also had a great deal of difficulty finding an answer on google so I'm sorry if I'm missing some glaring detail.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: If you use [type specifications](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), you'll have to pass only specific types to your functions, thus allowing your IDE to provide autocompletion for these types

Comment: I'm not sure if complex inheritance hierarchies will be as equally recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would obviously only want the Python function to be able to accept a specific class or interface

Python has support for *gradual typing*: you can choose to put type annotations on your functions (see [PEP 3107](https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/) and [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-484/))

```py
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

Python on its own doesn't care about these annotations, and won't stop you from calling `add` with a string and a socket. However, there are external tools called "type checkers", such as [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) that understand these annotations.

These type annotations also help IDEs with autocompletion, which seems to be your main concern. Here's a screenshot from PyCharm:

[image]